# Random avatar change

Tags: bug, profile-page

For some reason my avatar just randomly changed over the weekend from the one on the left to the one on the right [image]

Is there any reason that it was changed? I did not do so deliberately but I certainly could have accidentally done it if such a thing is possible.

I don't mind the new one, but I have been posting with the old one for several years, so if I can revert it I would prefer to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This change is intentional, see [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389123/263383) for further information. As for getting your old image back:

> While we do not recommend you to continue using your old identicon, we can give you back the image so that you may upload it as a custom avatar. Please [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) asking for it and we'll be able to give you the image.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe I should keep the new one then. It seems like in principle (given infinite computing power) one could reconstruct some PII from just the image itself.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Is the color fixed as well ? Or can we change the colour without changing the design?

Comment: @Aurelius there are no options to change the generated picture. But you can of course download the picture, edit it - e. g. to have a different color - then upload the edited picture as a new profile picture